# Nextjs 13.5 hydration failed

Tags: typescript, next.js, hydration

```
`'use client';

    import GridSection from '@/_core/components/grid-section/GridSection';
    import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
    import { ReactNode, useEffect } from 'react';
    import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
    import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
    import styles from './Admin.module.scss';
    import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar';

    const Layout = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const token = cookies.get('token');
    useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
      window.location.href = '/login';
    }
    }, []);

    return (
    <div className={styles.admin}>
      {token ? (
        <ChakraProvider>
          <GridSection
            bannerUrl="***.jpeg"
            isAdmin={true}
          >
            <main className={styles.container}>
              <Sidebar />
              <div className={styles.main}>{children}</div>
            </main>
          </GridSection>
        </ChakraProvider>
      ) : (
        1
      )}
    </div>
  );
    };

    export default Layout;`
```

I am here working on the layout of my interface, and I want it to operate on the client side. I don't want unauthorized users to access the underlying pages, but I'm receiving an error. I can't figure out what the issue is.

`warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.     at div     at GridSection (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/_core/components/grid-section/GridSection.tsx:17:11)     at EnvironmentProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@chakra-ui/react-env/dist/chunk-VMD3UMGK.mjs:34:11)     at ColorModeProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@chakra-ui/color-mode/dist/chunk-AMBGAKG2.mjs:29:5)     at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-c39617d8.browser.esm.js:123:50)     at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@chakra-ui/system/dist/chunk-MFVQSVQB.mjs:30:11)     at ChakraProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@chakra-ui/provider/dist/chunk-3DDHO3UN.mjs:21:5)     at ChakraProvider2 (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@chakra-ui/react/dist/chunk-QAITB7GG.mjs:19:5)     at div     at Layout (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/(admin)/layout.tsx:22:11)     at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:241:11)     at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:72:9)     at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:80:11)     at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9)     at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)     at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:338:11)     at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:110:11)     at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:152:9)     at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:227:11)     at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:15:44)     at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:348:11)     at div     at div     at body     at html     at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:72:9)     at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:80:11)     at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9)     at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)     at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:32:11)     at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)     at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:294:11)     at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:157:11)     at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:82:9)     at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:110:11)     at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:440:13)     at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:126:11)     at RSCComponent     at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:142:11) window.console.error @ app-index.js:32 Show 1 more frame Show less react-dom.development.js:6824 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.     at throwOnHydrationMismatch (react-dom.development.js:6824:9)     at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (react-dom.development.js:6869:7)     at updateHostComponent$1 (react-dom.development.js:15553:5)     at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:17397:14)     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:19465:14)     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (react-dom.development.js:19514:16)     at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:19589:29)     at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:25723:7)     at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24552:12)     at workLoopConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:24538:5)     at renderRootConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:24494:9)     at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:23358:38)     at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:261:34)     at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:230:14)     at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:534:21) app-index.js:32 Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>. window.console.error @ app-index.js:32 Show 1 more frame Show less 5on-recoverable-error.js:20 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.     at throwOnHydrationMismatch (react-dom.development.js:6824:9)     at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (react-dom.development.js:6869:7)     at updateHostComponent$1 (react-dom.development.js:15553:5)     at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:17397:14)     at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:25701:14)     at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24552:12)     at workLoopConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:24538:5)     at renderRootConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:24494:9)     at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:23358:38)     at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:261:34)     at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:230:14)     at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:534:21) react-dom.development.js:15501 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.     at updateHostRoot (react-dom.development.js:15501:57)     at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:17380:14)     at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:25701:14)     at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24552:12)     at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24268:5)     at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:24223:7)     at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:23451:20)     at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:23396:26)     at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:261:34)     at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:230:14)     at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:534:21)`